# Cant get infinispan distribution cache using EmbeddedCacheManager object when try to get same cache again in second node

Tags: jboss, infinispan, jgroups

I am using infinispan 8.1.3 for my SIP application server which was created with plain java. My server always get stuck when i start server as a secondth node. it always stuck when loading  "particular cache" from embedded cachemanager. how to solve this ??.thanks

working server log that particular cache(serviceWithId):

```
        2017-11-30 19:24:47,143 DEBUG [ServiceFinder] (main) No service impls found: FilterIndexingServiceProvider
    2017-11-30 19:24:47,144 DEBUG [InterceptorChain] (main) Interceptor chain size: 8
    2017-11-30 19:24:47,144 DEBUG [InterceptorChain] (main) Interceptor chain is:
            >> org.infinispan.interceptors.distribution.DistributionBulkInterceptor
            >> org.infinispan.interceptors.InvocationContextInterceptor
            >> org.infinispan.interceptors.CacheMgmtInterceptor
            >> org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferInterceptor
            >> org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.NonTransactionalLockingInterceptor
            >> org.infinispan.interceptors.EntryWrappingInterceptor
            >> org.infinispan.interceptors.distribution.NonTxDistributionInterceptor
            >> org.infinispan.interceptors.CallInterceptor
    2017-11-30 19:24:47,149 DEBUG [JmxUtil] (main) Object name org.infinispan:type=Cache,name="serviceWithId(dist_sync)",manager="tcp-cachecontainer",component=Cache already registered
    2017-11-30 19:24:47,150 DEBUG [LocalTopologyManagerImpl] (main) Node IVR-17268 joining cache serviceWithId
    2017-11-30 19:24:47,156 DEBUG [LocalTopologyManagerImpl] (main) Updating local topology for cache serviceWithId: CacheTopology{id=0, rebalanceId=0, currentCH=DefaultConsistentHash{ns=60, owners = (1)[IVR-17268: 60+0]}, pendingCH=null, unionCH=null, actualMembers=[IVR-17268]}
    2017-11-30 19:24:47,157 DEBUG [StateConsumerImpl] (main) Adding inbound state transfer for segments [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59] of cache serviceWithId
    2017-11-30 19:24:47,157 DEBUG [StateConsumerImpl] (main) Removing no longer owned entries for cache serviceWithId
    2017-11-30 19:24:47,160 DEBUG [CacheImpl] (main) Started cache serviceWithId on IVR-17268
 --------------loading all cache like this-------------------
```

Not working server log that particular cache :

```
    2017-11-30 19:25:39,680 DEBUG [ServiceFinder] (main) No service impls found: FilterIndexingServiceProvider
    2017-11-30 19:25:39,681 DEBUG [InterceptorChain] (main) Interceptor chain size: 8
    2017-11-30 19:25:39,681 DEBUG [InterceptorChain] (main) Interceptor chain is:
            >> org.infinispan.interceptors.distribution.DistributionBulkInterceptor
            >> org.infinispan.interceptors.InvocationContextInterceptor
            >> org.infinispan.interceptors.CacheMgmtInterceptor
            >> org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferInterceptor
            >> org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.NonTransactionalLockingInterceptor
            >> org.infinispan.interceptors.EntryWrappingInterceptor
            >> org.infinispan.interceptors.distribution.NonTxDistributionInterceptor
            >> org.infinispan.interceptors.CallInterceptor
    2017-11-30 19:25:39,691 DEBUG [JmxUtil] (main) Object name org.infinispan:type=Cache,name="serviceWithId(dist_sync)",manager="tcp-cachecontainer",component=Cache already registered
    2017-11-30 19:25:39,691 DEBUG [LocalTopologyManagerImpl] (main) Node IVR-52151 joining cache serviceWithId
    2017-11-30 19:25:39,703 DEBUG [LocalTopologyManagerImpl] (main) Updating local topology for cache serviceWithId: CacheTopology{id=0, rebalanceId=0, currentCH=DefaultConsistentHash{ns=60, owners = (1)[IVR-17268: 60+0]}, pendingCH=null, unionCH=null, actualMembers=[IVR-17268]}
    2017-11-30 19:25:39,708 DEBUG [LocalTopologyManagerImpl] (transport-thread-IVR-p4-t6) Updating local topology for cache serviceWithId: CacheTopology{id=1, rebalanceId=1, currentCH=DefaultConsistentHash{ns=60, owners = (1)[IVR-17268: 60+0]}, pendingCH=DefaultConsistentHash{ns=60, owners = (2)[IVR-17268: 30+30, IVR-52151: 30+30]}, unionCH=null, actualMembers=[IVR-17268, IVR-52151]}
    2017-11-30 19:25:39,708 DEBUG [LocalTopologyManagerImpl] (transport-thread-IVR-p4-t6) Starting local rebalance for cache serviceWithId, topology = CacheTopology{id=1, rebalanceId=1, currentCH=DefaultConsistentHash{ns=60, owners = (1)[IVR-17268: 60+0]}, pendingCH=DefaultConsistentHash{ns=60, owners = (2)[IVR-17268: 30+30, IVR-52151: 30+30]}, unionCH=null, actualMembers=[IVR-17268, IVR-52151]}
    2017-11-30 19:25:39,709 DEBUG [StateConsumerImpl] (transport-thread-IVR-p4-t6) Adding inbound state transfer for segments [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59] of cache serviceWithId
    2017-11-30 19:25:39,718 DEBUG [StateConsumerImpl] (transport-thread-IVR-p4-t6) Removing no longer owned entries for cache serviceWithId
--------------------stuck here---------------------------
```

sample code:

```
    private static EmbeddedCacheManager  dcm = MediaServer.getCacheManager();       
    public static Cache<Object, Call> simpleCalls = dcm.getCache("callWithCallId");
    public static AdvancedCache<Object,Call> callWithCallId = simpleCalls.getAdvancedCache();
    public static Cache<Integer, Integer> freePortPoolCache = dcm.getCache("freePortPool");
    public static AdvancedCache<Integer,Integer> freePortPool = freePortPoolCache.getAdvancedCache();    
    public static Cache<Object, Object> serviceWithId = dcm.getCache("serviceWithId");
```

configuration file:

```
<infinispan
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="urn:infinispan:config:8.1 http://www.infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-8.1.xsd"
      xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:8.1">


<jgroups>

     <stack-file name="udp" path="jgroups-udp.xml" />

  </jgroups>
  <cache-container name="tcp-cachecontainer" default-cache="the-default-cache">
      <transport stack="udp" node-name="IVR" cluster="main"/>
       <!-- <jmx duplicate-domains="true" /> -->
        <distributed-cache name="callObject" >
                <transaction mode="NON_DURABLE_XA" locking="PESSIMISTIC"  auto-commit="true" />
                <locking  striping="false" acquire-timeout="5000" />
        </distributed-cache>
        <distributed-cache name="userObjectsWithTelId" owners="2" mode="SYNC"/>
        <distributed-cache name="conferenceWithPin" owners="2" mode="SYNC" />
        <distributed-cache name="parkCallWithCallId" owners="2" mode="SYNC"/>
        <distributed-cache name="activeAgentHash" owners="2" mode="SYNC"/>
        <distributed-cache name="parkCallHash" owners="2" mode="SYNC"/>
        <distributed-cache name="callWithCallId" owners="2" mode="SYNC"/>
        <distributed-cache name="epointWithCallId" owners="2" mode="SYNC"/>
        <distributed-cache name="freePortPool" owners="2" mode="SYNC"/>
        <distributed-cache name="activeRegisteredUsers" owners="2" mode="SYNC"/>
        <distributed-cache name="activeCalls" owners="2" mode="SYNC"/>
        <distributed-cache name="serviceWithId" owners="2" mode="SYNC"/>
        <distributed-cache name="ivrMessageCache" owners="2" mode="SYNC" />
        <distributed-cache name="sipproxyMessageCache"  owners="2" mode="SYNC" capacity="0"/>
        <distributed-cache name="ivrServiceEvent"  owners="2" mode="SYNC" capacity="0"/>
   </cache-container>
</infinispan>
```

Thread dump for above case:

```
https://pastebin.com/RVBPCgZQ
```

Comment: Do you have a simple reproducer to share?

Comment: When you report something to be 'stuck', please grab stacktraces using `jstack` and link them through pastebin-like service.

Comment: @RadimVansa thanks!! i pasted thread dump in   https://pastebin.com/RVBPCgZQ

Comment: @jagadeeshk The node is not waiting for any RPC. It just sits idle and it looks like it has already installed the topology id=1 (was this installed on the first node as well?). What do you expect it to do?

Comment: @RadimVansa thanks, the problem is, i have a one distribution cache(calls) which is shared by multiple nodes   1. if calls cache is not empty in firstnode, seconde node got hang when getting "calls cache" from cachemanager while starting second node  2.if calls cache is empty in first node , no problem starting second node

Comment: @jagadeeshk The information you've provided above is not enough to find out what is happening. Try to create a minimal reproducer.